# ViewHolder gets a null reference for a custom view when used in a RecycleView adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following RecycleView adapter:

```
class PageViewerAdapter(val context: Context, private val pages: List<Page>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PageViewerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_viewer_card, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.testView.text = position.toString()
        holder.panelView.isEnabled = false
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return pages.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val testView: TextView = itemView.test_text
        val panelView: PanelView = itemView.page_preview
    }
}
```

The problem is that `itemView.page_preview`, which is referencing my custom view in the XML, is null. Both in `ViewHolder` initialization and in the `onBindViewHolder`.

This is the RecyclerView card/item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     <my.package.PanelView
         android:id="@+id/page_preview"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W, 1:1.4142"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If however, the `page_preview` references are removed from `ViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`, the views will load fine within a few seconds.

**Update**

This is the custom view class:

```
class PanelView:
    (context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : SurfaceView(context), SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private var canvasThread: CanvasThread

    init {
        this.holder.addCallback(this)
        canvasThread = CanvasThread(this.holder, this)
        this.isFocusable = true
    }

    override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        resume()
    }

    override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        pause()
    }

    fun resume() {
        if (!canvasThread.isAlive) {
            canvasThread = CanvasThread(this.holder, this)
            canvasThread.run = true
            canvasThread.start()
        }
    }

    fun pause() {
        if (canvasThread.isAlive) {
            var retry = true
            canvasThread.run = false
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    canvasThread.join()
                    retry = false
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your PanelView class?

Comment: PanelView is the PageView, sorry for the confusion. Updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `kotlinx.android.synthetic` import statements to access your specific within the parent view. This does not work for recycler views, instead you should do `val panelView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.page_preview)`

Comment: Using `val panelView: PanelView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.page_preview)` instead unfortunately makes no difference. It still produces a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlinx synthetic doesn't work by default in RecyclerView.ViewHolder class, you need to have it extend `kotlinx.android.extensions.LayoutContainer`:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), LayoutContainer {
    val testView: TextView = itemView.test_text //now this will work
    val panelView: PanelView = itemView.page_preview
}
```

Anyway, you should really be careful with syntetic imports as they can be a headache to debug, especially in fragments. You might as well just use the fancy new `findViewById<View>`

Edit 1:
Since you've posted your custom view class, at first glance it seems that the super constructor invocation isn't right. You could use the following for all custom view kotlin classes:

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    ctx: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttrs: Int = 0
) : View(ctx, attrs, defStyleAttrs)
```

Comment: If it's just with your own custom view, then you've answered yourself. Partially, at least. Meaning it's not a RecyclerView.ViewHolder issue, but rather one with your custom view

Comment: I have updated the question to include the custom view code. Do you mind taking a look?

Comment: It's best to stop using `kotlinx.android.synthetic`, since its basically deprecated: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/ I'm not sure whether `kotlinx.android.extensions` is also deprecated.

Comment: I did try it by using explicit findViewById, but it didn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem: see if your custom view renders correctly in an activity on its own; if not, start commenting the lines in the class until you find the issue. For me, it doesn't appear to be a RecyclerView issue and I can't figure out anything that's wrong without debugging that view